# Calling method getting , cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java

### Getting cannot be applied to given types.

below code gives compilation error.

```
private void getMessageBody(List<String> eObjects){ 

     HashMap<String, Object> objMap=new HashMap<String, Object>();

     List<HashMap<String, Object>> contextObjectList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

     if(eObject!=null){

            for(String eObject : eObjects){
                  objMap = (HashMap<String, Object>) JSON.ConvertToObject(eObject, HashMap.class);
                  contextObjectList.add(objMap);
            }
     }else{
            objMap = new HashMap();   
     }

    CustomUtility.convertMessageBody(contextObjectList,template.getSubject());
}


public class CustomUtility {

          public static String convertMessageBody(List<HashMap<String, Object>> templateContextList,
                                       String templateBody) {
                        //rest of bussiness code.
          }
}
```

### Compilation Error.

```
 error: method convertMessageBody in class CustomUtility cannot be applied to given types;
```

not able to understand why above compilation error is getting. help to understand.

Comment: What is the type of `template.getSubject()` ?

Comment: @Berger , type is STRING for template.getSubject().

Answer (score 0):

It means that the method signature for `convertMessageBody` does not accept the type of parameters you are passing to it.  In particular, it is expecting `List<HashMap<String, Object>>` and a `String` and it looks like `template.getSubject()` does not return a `String`.

Comment: Second parameter in method `convertMessageBody ` i am getting string value. and even if remove second parameter in both place getting same compilation error.

Comment: Are you sure you've recompiled it?  I've just tried your code and not got any errors of that type;  The only error was that `convertMessageBody` should return a String.